# How to securely install things not in /opt so they can update themselves

Tags: apt, software-installation, firefox

I use firefox from mozilla.org, not from APT which is old. However, if I place it at /opt, it cannot update itself, because /opt is owned by root.

If I simply place it at /home, then it can update itself but any executable can modify it, which is unsecure.

What would be the ideal way of doing this, without using package managers? (even ones with modern firefox)

Comment: Locking down permissions so only your user can see, modify and execute the file.

Comment: The current version of Firefox today in *every currently-supported release of Ubuntu* is 76.0.1, same as the version you download today direct from Mozilla. The Ubuntu Security Team keeps Firefox up to date. If apt is offering you older versions, then you have a problem with your sources that needs to be fixed...like simply enabling the -security pocket.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps  so that firefox can update itself :

Open Terminal then,

1) Move or copy the firefox tar file in opt directory by this command :  `sudo mv /home/username/Download/Firefox.tar.bz2  /opt/`

2) Then extract the firefox tar file there with appropriate command . You can search "how to extract a particular type of file in linux".

3) After extracting a folder named firefox will be created in the "opt" folder. Then type this command to get access to the firefox folder :

```
cd /opt
sudo chown -R username:groupname firefox/
```

This way you can directly update firefox without the need of downloading  firefox.tar file from mozilla.org.

Or you can install firefox via same methods in `/usr/local/` directory if you do not want to install in /opt directory.

If you have any doubt then ask.

Comment: this would make the opt/firefox folder accessible to any binary, which would be insecure